# What Google oAuth 2 application type should I use for web and mobile apps? Will Cognito recognise them as the same?

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I want to make use of social auth from Google for apps and websites.

Using the [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com) I have three account types to choose from:

- Service
- Web
- Installed

And Installed gives me options for:

- Android
- Chrome
- iOS

Given I support iOS and Android, should I create credentials for each?

Also in the mix in AWS Cognito. If I use the credentials from each of these options will they ultimately resolve to the same Cognito ID if a user authenticates on all of the platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cognito and IAM have launched [generic OpenID Connect support](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3LP54JOGBE0AY/Building-an-App-using-Amazon-Cognito-and-an-OpenID-Connect-Identity-Provider). With this launch, you can now create an OpenId Connect provider [in IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#providers) with all of the client ids created in the Google console.

From there, you can configure your identity pool with that provider in the [Cognito console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=us-east-1). After that, Cognito will be able to identify users of your application regardless of which platform (iOS/Android/Web) they authenticate with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to create separate "client IDs" for each of the application. If they are for the same overall application, then they should be in the same project.
The reason you need to create separate client id is that each platform has different security properties and we need more information specific to that use case.
For example, on the web, we rely on redirect url to give you back the token, but on Android, you need to give us the package name and hash of the cert.

But if a user approves your application once on the web then on android for the same scopes you'll get auto approval.

Not 100% sure about Amazon Cognito but you should get the same ID (from Google) for the same user and that should tie back to same Cognito ID.
BTW, You should also look at Google Identity Toolkit.